# sumar resultados de una función en python

Tags: python

partiendo del siguiente codigo:

```
 print("Bienvenido a la balanza interactiva de SEBAS AYALA SUPERMARKET")
 print("A continuación, te indicamos los codigos de cada producto:") 
 print("\n1)Manzana \n2)Naranja \n3)Frutilla")
 intentos = int(input("introduce la cantidad de productos en tu carrito: "))

 def balanza_virtual(): 

    frutas = ("manzanas", "naranjas", "frutillas")
    producto = int(input("introduce el codigo de tu producto: "))
    peso = int(input("introduce el peso de tu producto en gramos: "))

    manzana = 15
    naranja = 20
    frutilla = 30

    calculo1 = peso * manzana/100
    calculo2 = peso * naranja/100
    calculo3 = peso * frutilla/100

    if producto == 1 and peso >= 1000:
       print(f"el precio de {peso/1000} kl de {frutas[0]} es: ${calculo1} ")
    elif producto == 1 and peso < 1000:
       print(f"el precio de {peso} gr de {frutas[0]} es: ${calculo1} ")

    if producto == 2 and peso >= 1000: 
       print(f"el precio de {peso/1000} kl de {frutas[1]} es: ${calculo2} ")
    elif producto == 2 and peso < 1000:
       print(f"el precio de {peso} gr de {frutas[1]} es: ${calculo2} ")

     if producto == 3 and peso >= 1000: 
       print(f"el precio de {peso/1000} kl de {frutas[2]} es: ${calculo3} ")  
     elif producto == 3 and peso < 1000:
       print(f"el precio de {peso} gr de {frutas[2]} es: ${calculo3} ")
   

  for i in range(intentos): 
  balanza_virtual()
```

como puedo hacer para obtener la suma de los precios de los elementos ingresados por el usuario? posiblemente existe formas mucho mas completas y mejoradas de hacer esta función, de momento solo se me ocurre esta. Pero tengo el problema de que no se como obtener la suma total del dinero gastado por el usuario una vez introducidos los datos.

Answer (score 2):

No he modificado nada de lo que hiciste de tu programa, lo único que añadí, fue una lista donde se van metiendo todo el dinero (a través de append). Después, con una función llamada suma, se van sumando los elementos que hay dentro (aquí usamos sum(dentro la lista)) una vez eso lo sacamos afuera y lo escribimos una vez acabe el bucle for.

Espero que te sea útil

```
def suma(dinero):
    la_suma = sum(dinero)
    return la_suma


def balanza_virtual():
    frutas = ("manzanas", 15, "naranjas", 20, "frutillas", 30)
    producto = int(input("introduce el codigo de tu producto: "))
    peso = int(input("introduce el peso de tu producto en gramos: "))
    precio_total = []

    if producto == 1 and peso >= 1000:
       precio_total.append((peso * frutas[1])/100)
       print(f"el precio de {peso/1000} kl de {frutas[0]} es: ${(peso * frutas[1])/100} ")
    elif producto == 1 and peso < 1000:
       precio_total.append((peso * frutas[1]) / 100)
       print(f"el precio de {peso} gr de {frutas[0]} es: ${(peso * frutas[1])/100} ")

    if producto == 2 and peso >= 1000:
       precio_total.append((peso * frutas[3]) / 100)
       print(f"el precio de {peso/1000} kl de {frutas[2]} es: ${(peso * frutas[3])/100} ")
    elif producto == 2 and peso < 1000:
       precio_total.append((peso * frutas[3]) / 100)
       print(f"el precio de {peso} gr de {frutas[2]} es: ${(peso * frutas[3])/100} ")

    if producto == 3 and peso >= 1000:
       precio_total.append((peso * frutas[5]) / 100)
       print(f"el precio de {peso/1000} kl de {frutas[4]} es: ${(peso * frutas[5])/100} ")
    elif producto == 3 and peso < 1000:
       precio_total.append((peso * frutas[5]) / 100)
       print(f"el precio de {peso} gr de {frutas[4]} es: ${(peso * frutas[5])/100} ")

    return precio_total


print("A continuación, te indicamos los codigos de cada producto:")
print("\n1)Manzana \n2)Naranja \n3)Frutilla")
intentos = int(input("introduce la cantidad de productos en tu carrito: "))

dinero = []
for i in range(intentos):
    dinero = balanza_virtual()

print('El dinero total gastado es:  ' + str(suma(dinero)))
```

Answer (score 0):

El código está más complicado de lo que debería ser porque no estás trabajando con una estructura de datos adecuada. No es buena idea colocar datos, como la lista de frutas, dentro de funciones.

Yo sugeriría trabajes con una estructura tipo diccionario `{clave1:valor1, ...}`, donde las claves serán el código del producto, y el valor es otra estructura donde va el nombre, el precio y podrían ir otras cosas como la cantidad en inventario, descripción, etc...
En este caso puse las claves como un *string* porque es lo más usual. En un programa real, este campo podría ser (por ejemplo) un código de barras escaneable.

```
productos = {
    "100" : {"nombre": "manzana", "precio": 15},
    "200" : {"nombre": "naranja", "precio": 20},
    "300" : {"nombre": "frutilla", "precio": 30}
}
```

Se puede construir 2 funciones. Una para listar todos los productos y otra para agregar productos a un `carro`.
La variable `carro` es otra estructura de datos tipo diccionario que va acumulando valores de esta forma: `{cod1: cantidad1, cod2: cantidad2, ...}` Ver documentación: [dicionario.get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

```
def listar_productos():
    print(f'Codigo - Nombre - Precio')
    for cod, prod in productos.items():
        print(f'{cod} - {prod["nombre"]} - {prod["precio"]}')
        
def balanza_virtual(carro):
    while True:
        cod = input("Introduce el codigo del producto | [deje vacio] para salir: ")
        if cod == "":
            break
        if cod in productos:
            prod = productos[cod]['nombre']
            cant = int(input(f"Peso del producto [{prod}] en gramos: "))
            carro[cod] = carro.get(cod, 0) + cant
        else:
            print("ERROR: No hay productos con ese código")
    return carro
```

Falta hacer una función que haga los cálculos cuando ya se no se quiere agregar más nada al carro.

```
def imprimir_compra(carro):
    total = 0
    for cod, cant in carro.items():
        prod = productos[cod]['nombre']
        peso = f"{cant} gr" if cant < 1000 else f"{cant/1000} kg"
        subtotal = cant * productos[cod]['precio'] / 100
        print(f"El precio de {peso} {prod} es: {subtotal}")
        total += subtotal
    print("---------")
    print("El total de la compra es:", total)
```

Finalmente el programa principal será:

```
carro = {}
while True:
    print()
    print("1 - Listar Productos\n2 - Agregar al carro\nx - Salir")
    op = input("Seleccione una opcion: ")
    print()
    if op == "1":
        listar_productos()
    elif op == "2":
        carro = balanza_virtual(carro)
        print()
        imprimir_compra(carro)
    else:
        break

print("Programa terminado")
```

Si juntas todos los bloques de código en el mismo orden, incluyendo el diccionario inicial, funcionará.

Nota: El diccionario `carro` se mantendrá con los datos hasta que el programa se cierre, o sea, puedes seguir agregando más items. Si quieres cambiar este comportamiento, puedes hacer una función de "nueva_compra" y limpiar el diccionario `carro`, o también puedes simplemente mover la línea `carro = {}` justo después de `elif op == "2":`.